# is EJB name query validation during build instead of deploy time possible?

Tags: java, maven, ejb

I recently had to do a major refactor of an older code base at work. It involved changing a lot of objects, variable names, and where things were stored/retrieved. We're building 2 EJB3 projects with maven and deploying them to glassfish 4 instance.

I'd like to know if it's possible to test for named query validation at build time instead of deploy time. I've spent the last few hours deploying, it failing due to a bad named query, fixing it, redeploying, rinse and repeat. It's getting on my nerves.

Comment: Since JPA is supported in Java SE environment, you may want to add a set of junit tests that sets up Entity Manager against test database and run those named queries.

Comment: I was afraid of that. There was never even the notion of testing this project before I got to it. I at least wanted a working build to save as a back up before I started  adding the tests. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Named query errors before deploying could be tracked using Netbeans IDE.
For every named query inside entity beans if it is malformed Netbeans IDE shows a warning message in the line that has named query.
But then one has to visit each entity bean individually but then this practice would save a lot of time over deploying and then finding a error.
I personally  find it very convenient.